CloudFront + Ubuntu EC2 +Custom Port works for HTTP but not for HTTPS
I am trying to use CF -> EC2 with domain from Route 53 and SSL from ACM but this URL works only on HTTP and on HTTPS, it returns 504 ERROR: The request could not be satisfied.:

The EC2 is running Ubuntu+Python+Flask+Waitress to serve an api on port 5000. I have enabled all IP4/IP6 In/outbound traffic in EC2 config, disable the firewall in Ubuntu and can access it directly via http://IP address, which works fine.
Any ideas why it works for HTTP but not for HTTPs? It should route HTTPS traffic to port 5000 right?


You can't use the same port for both HTTP and HTTPS.

@Gerald Schneider, I actually tried setting the HTTPS to 5000 and HTTP to 5001 but it still doesnt work

Well, if your app only listens for HTTP set it to HTTP only. otherwise it will try to use HTTPS when HTTPS is requested, which obviously will not work on a HTTP only port. Or configure your app to listen to HTTPS as well on another port. It's documented pretty thoroughly.

Thank you that is very useful!
